# "socket hang up" error when calling Google API via node client

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Below code calls the Google Analytics Reporting API using Google's nodejs client version `0.7` [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client). It returns a `socket hang up` error on some executions but not always. Would this be errors on Google's servers' end? Is there an easy way to debug? BTW I'm making several calls consecutively, not sure if it's caused by rate limits.

```
gapi = require "googleapis"
authClient = new gapi.auth.JWT(
  config.ga.clientEmail,
  config.ga.privateKeyPath,
  null,
  [config.ga.scopeUri]
)

authPromise = new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
  authClient.authorize (err, token) ->
      resolve token
    return
  return

authPromise.then ->
  gapi.discover('analytics', 'v3')
    .withAuthClient(authClient)
    .execute (err, client) ->
      ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error surfaced after successfully getting the client then running:
`client.analytics.data.ga.get(queryObj).execute (err, result) -> ....`

Ryan Seys, a contributor on the API client, suggested [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/185#issuecomment-45513439) that `.discover` should be called once and the resulting `client` should reused. I was calling `.discover` hundreds of times consecutively and creating a bunch of new `client`s. Server probably didn't like that. By storing and reusing the `client` the issue went away. Working code for prosperity:

```
gapi = require "googleapis"
authClient = new gapi.auth.JWT(
  config.ga.clientEmail,
  config.ga.privateKeyPath,
  null,
  [config.ga.scopeUri]
)

authPromise = new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
  authClient.authorize (err, token) ->
    gapi.discover('analytics', 'v3').withAuthClient(authClient).execute (err, client) ->
      resolve client
      return
    return
  return

authPromise.then (client) ->
  client.analytics.data.ga.get(queryObj).execute (err, result) ->
```